# Did vlc remove lib and other sdk files and folders from vlc installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vlc, libvlc

I downloaded and installed latest VLC version 2.2.1 and i noticed i can't access VLC header files in Visual Studio Project. So i quickly looked inside VLC installation directory and i found that neither include files exist nor lib files exist.

So now how can i use libvlc in my project any workaround?

I can't find any lib files and header files in vlc installation folder.
I use Visual Studio 2013, Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC binary installers for Windows do not include the LibVLC SDK. It would be a waste of bandwidth and space for most users.
You can find the SDK files, i.e. development headers and import libraries, from the plain VLC 7zip/ZIP packages in the sdk directory. Alternatively, you can build VLC from [source](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html).

For downloading VLC 7zip/ZIP packages, visit **[THIS](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/)** link, choose your required VLC version, choose platform i.e. win32 or win64, and click on vlc-**version-win32/win64.7z** or **vlc-version-win32/win64.zip**