# Where to download libvlc?

Tags: c++, windows, vlc, libvlc

I can't find where to download libvlc.
In fact I already use it in a Windows application I'm developping but I don't remember where I got it and wanted to have a more recent version and the licence info as I read it is LGPL but still not sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/mfkl/libvlc-nuget and https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows/

Comment: Old post but since its top on Google, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467057/did-vlc-remove-lib-and-other-sdk-files-and-folders-from-vlc-installation
In short, just download the 7z/zip package and the SDK with libs is there.

Answer (score 6):

In their wiki page :

> Warning: Please, do not put pre-release test binaries or git-compiles
>   on software sites or on user-forums. We've had bad experiences with
>   this before and we do not appreciate it.

It seems that they want you to pull the code and compile it yourself.

this the code page:
https://wiki.videolan.org/GetTheSource/

and this instruction on windows:
https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, so it is for building the whole VLC, is it building the libvlc too ?what about https://github.com/RSATom/libvlc-sdk ? There's libs file but no dll...

Comment: If it provides .lib without .dll. this usually means that it is a static library which you do not need a dll to run it.

Comment: This is what I thought but it doesn't work for me...

Comment: If I were you I would compile it in the configuration I need then I will use it

Answer (score 2):

Just reinstall [standard] `vlc`.  It knows where it was installed previously and has a copy of the library.  No need to install the library separately.  If you used standard install, this will be:

```
C:Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC
```

and the libraries will be in there

Comment: The standard version only includes the `dll`s, not the `lib`s, so it can't be built against.  There's a [wiki page that discusses generating the libs from the dlls](https://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll/) that looks promising.